# Приоритеты c++-шаблонов

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Есть вот такой код:

```cpp
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

// (1)
template <typename L, typename R>
struct combine {
    using type = tuple<L, R>;
};

// (2)
template <typename T>
struct combine<T, T> {
    using type = vector<T>;
};

// (3)
template <typename ... Ts, typename T>
struct combine<tuple<Ts...>, T> {
    using type = tuple<Ts..., T>;
};

// (4)
template <typename ... Ts, typename ... Us>
struct combine<tuple<Ts...>, tuple<Us...>> {
    using type = tuple<Ts..., Us...>;
};

int main() {
    using result = typename combine<tuple<int, char>, tuple<int, char>>::type;

    return 0;
};
```

Как ни странно, компилятор начал ругаться на неопределённость:

```cpp
main.cpp:26:72: error: ambiguous template instantiation for 'struct combine<std::tuple<int, char>, std::tuple<int, char> >'
   26 |     using result = typename combine<tuple<int, char>, tuple<int, char>>::type;
      |                                                                        ^~
main.cpp:11:8: note: candidates are: 'template<class T> struct combine<T, T> [with T = std::tuple<int, char>]'
   11 | struct combine<T, T> {
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:16:8: note:                 'template<class ... Ts, class T> struct combine<std::tuple<_Tps ...>, T> [with Ts = {int, char}; T = std::tuple<int, char>]'
   16 | struct combine<tuple<Ts...>, T> {
```

Собственно вопрос в том, как помочь компилятору решить неоднозначность. Хотелось бы, чтобы правило (2) было в приоритете. Единственное, что пришло в голову - добавить в combine дополнительный аргумент `Enable = void` для SFINAE и в правилах (3) и (4) прописать `enable_if_t<!is_same_v<tuple<Ts...>, T>>` и `enable_if_t<!is_same_v<tuple<Ts...>, tuple<Us...>>>` соответственно. Но по-моему это больше костыль, чем решение.

Answer (score 5):

Нужно добавить такую специализацию:

```
template <typename ...P>
struct combine<std::tuple<P...>, std::tuple<P...>>
{
    using type = std::vector<std::tuple<P...>>;
};
```

Но вообще, не нравится мне этот шаблон. Через пару месяцев вы сами-то вспомните, что `combine` с двумя одинаковыми `tuple` дает один результат, а с разными - другой?

Answer (score 0):

Сначала нужно определить общий шаблон, а потом частные случаи(частичные специализации). И нужно помнить, что если шаблон класса имеет пакет параметров шаблона, он должен появиться в конце списка параметров шаблона.

```
// (1) с неизвестным количеством параметров (больше оодного)
template <typename T, typename ... Ts>
struct combine {
    using type = tuple<Ts..., T>;
};

// (2) когда ровно два параметра
template <typename L, typename R>
struct combine<L, R> {
    using type = tuple<L, R>;
};

// (3) с одним параметром
template <typename T>
struct combine<T, T> {
    using type = vector<T>;
};
```

Comment: это понятно, но проблема в том, что combine всегда принимает 2 аргумента, и специализация combine зависит от типов аргументов ([T] + [T] = [T], (A, B) + (C, D) = (A, B, C, D) и т.д.). вопрос в том, можно ли каким-либо способом понизить или повысить приоритет специализации

Comment: Нет, повысить или понизить приоритет не получится. Сначала должен быть общий шаблон, потом частичные специализации, а потом фул специализации. Если (A, B, C, D) инстанцироваться будет по общему шаблону.

Comment: Вы в (1) аргументы местами меняете

Comment: @Cerbo, я добавил в ответ и ответ на ваш комментарий